# If $V\in L(H)$ is an isometry , then show that $V$ has unitary extension.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

The following problem was left as an exercise in my class of operator theory and I am not able to prove it.

Let $H$ be a Hilbert Space and let $V\in L(H)$ be an isometry. Show that $V $ always has a unitary extension.

Let $T\in L(H_1,H_2)$. Then T is called an isometry if $||Tx||_2 =||x||_1 \forall x\in H_1$.

T  is called a unitary operator if $T$ is a bijective isometry.

I have to show the existence of a Hilbert Space K containing H and a unitary operator $U\in L(K)$  such that $U|_{H} =V$.

I have to show that U is invertible and the isometry on V can be extended to U. But I am not getting any ideas on how can I prove these two assertions?

Do you mind helping me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $$H':=\operatorname{im}(V).$$
The corestriction $W:H\to H'$ of $V$ is an isometric isomorphism.

Define the Hilbert space$$K:=H\times H'.$$
Its subspace $H\times\{0\}$ being identified to $H,$ the following is a unitary extension of $V:$
$$\begin {matrix}U:&K&\to&K,\\&(x,y)&\mapsto&(V(x)+(I-p)(W^{-1}(y)),p(W^{-1}(y)))\end{matrix}$$
where $p\in L(H)$ is the orthogonal projection onto $H'.$

Comment: Something seems to not add up here? You are defining $U:\mathcal H\times\operatorname{im}V\to\operatorname{im}V\times\mathcal H$ via $U(x,y):=(Vx,V^*y)$ so domain and co-domain are not equal. But making them equal via $\operatorname{im}V\times\mathcal H\simeq\mathcal H\times\operatorname{im}V$ (as you do in the co-domain of $U$, where $=$ is rather $\simeq$) leads to the operator $(x,y)\mapsto(V^*y,Vx)$ which is not an extension of $V$ anymore.

Comment: I don't "make them equal" via the isomorphism you wrote. They *are* equal by the sequence of *true equalities* (and not isomorphisms) in my answer. And my $U$ is not what you wrote. $(x,0)$ is really sent to the subspace $H'\oplus0$ of $H\oplus0\subset H\oplus H'=K.$

Comment: I rewrote all this more formally, hopefully not damaging to much the readability

Comment: Looks great! So your $U$ operates as $(x,Vz)\mapsto(Vx+(I-VV^*)z,VV^*z)$ for all $x,z\in H$ which also gives a nice connection to the "larger" extension from my answer

Comment: If you say so... But it is a reformulation of my initial answer, which I personnaly found more understandable.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you very much for the answer. Can you please tell how you proved that $W $ is an isomorphism?

Comment: There is nothing to prove; $W$ is an isomorphism by definition, since $V$ is an isometry and $W$ is the corestriction to its image.

Comment: @AnneBauval But you didn't showed that extension U is unitary.

Comment: I didn't indeed. I leave it to you: either you find it (like me) obvious *by construction* (it was more obvious in [my initial formulation](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/4607203/2)), or you compute $U^*$ and check that $UU^*=U^*U=I,$ which is an easy but tedious exercise.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very abstract problem because it occurs exclusively in infinite dimensions ([due to every isometry on a finite-dimensional space automatically being unitary](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3145804/495075)). Thus to get a better feeling for it let us attempt to solve the problem just for the right-shift operator
\begin{align*}
V:\ell^2(\mathbb C)&\to\ell^2(\mathbb C)\\
(x_1,x_2,\ldots)&\mapsto (0,x_1,x_2,\ldots)
\end{align*}
which is the [prime example of an isometry which is not surjective (and hence not unitary)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/900311/495075). Extending this operator to something unitary means that we, in particular, have to "enlarge" the domain of $V$ somehow. A good first guess is to just take two copies, that is, $ K:= H\times H$ which [is indeed a Hilbert space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2606158/is-the-cartesian-product-of-two-hilbert-spaces-a-hilbert-space). Note that this is not the only choice for $ K$ as [Anne's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4607203/495075) shows.

If we choose to embed $ H\hookrightarrow  K$ via $x\mapsto\scriptstyle\begin{pmatrix}x\\0\end{pmatrix}$, then $U: K\to K$ is called an extension of $V$ if
$$
U\begin{pmatrix}x\\0\end{pmatrix}=U\begin{pmatrix}(x_1,x_2,\ldots)\\0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}V(x_1,x_2,\ldots)\\0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}(0,x_1,x_2,\ldots)\\0\end{pmatrix}
$$
for all $x\in\ell^2(\mathbb C)$.
Hence the action of $U$ on the first component is already determined; our job now is to define on the *second* component such that we get something bijective and isometric. One possibility (of infinitely many) is
$$
U\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}=U\begin{pmatrix}(x_1,x_2,\ldots)\\(y_1,y_2,\ldots)\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}(y_1,x_1,x_2,\ldots)\\(y_2,y_3,y_4,\ldots)\end{pmatrix},
$$
that is, we "fill the gap" caused by $V$ with the first element of the second component. It is obvious that $U$ is bijective and isometric.

Coming back to the general problem, i.e. to arbitrary $V$, let us express the above map $U$ using $V$:
$$
U\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}Vx+(y_1,0,0,\ldots)\\V^*y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}Vx+y-VV^*y\\V^*y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}Vx+(I-VV^*)y\\V^*y\end{pmatrix}\,.
$$
Now if (we can show that) the map
\begin{align*}
U: H\times H&\to  H\times H\\
\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}&\mapsto\begin{pmatrix}Vx+(I-VV^*)y\\V^*y\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
is a bijective linear isometry which satisfies $U(x,0)=(Vx,0)$ for all $x\in H$, then we are done. Indeed, proving this is straightforward, cf., e.g., Appendix 4 of *"Functional Analysis"* by F. Riesz and B. Sz.-Nagy (1990) or p. 6 in *"Completely Bounded Maps and Operator Algebras"* by V. Paulsen (2002).

Comment: Unrelated side note: had we not required domain and co-domain of $U$ to be the same, we could have extended $V$ "way smaller" via $U:H×(\operatorname{im}V)^\perp\to H$, $(x,y)↦Vx+y$